# How are USB IDs and Devices assigned in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, keyboard

I have a usb keyboard and I'm using the lsusb command. When I disconnect and reconnect the keyboard I see that `Device` increments, but `ID` stays fixed. The ID stays fixed even across machines. I don't have two identical devices to connect to one pc to see if the ID is the same. I wonder if I had two identical keyboards would they both have ID 040b:2000? When I think of IDs I think of UIDs, like my drivers id is unique and html ids are unique.

On my rpi:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 040b:2000 Weltrend Semiconductor
```

Disconnect keyboard and reconnect

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 040b:2000 Weltrend Semiconductor
```

Then take the keyboard to my pc and

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 040b:2000 Weltrend Semiconductor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the USB ID is device-standard, so 2 identical devices will have the same ID.  A database of IDs and devices (and support in Linux, etc) is maintained at http://www.linux-usb.org/usb-ids.html.  The actual number is broken down into 2 parts - vendor and device.

Answer (score 3):

Every USB device, by requirement of the standard, must have two basic parameters, Vendor Identifier (VID), and Product Identifier (PID). These identifiers are transmitted by every USB device during enumeration stage, in "get descriptor" command. The VID and PID are embedded into device hardware, and thus are OS-independent. In addition to the generic USB class of a device, their purpose is to let OS load proper driver if the device has proprietary functions specific for this vendor.

VIDs are assigned to every manufacturer registered with USB organisation. The USB.ORG has a list of unique VIDs assigned to manufacturers. The PID is an additional identifier of a device, it describes different device types and  model versions within the manufacturer's line of product.

So yes, two keyboards from the same store shelf will report exactly the same VID and PID. These should not be confused with identification of instances of drivers ("handles") that are internally assigned by OS to every connected USB device and can vary depending on the order how devices were plugged in and discovered.